# googlebot crawling content that was loaded by ajax?

Tags: ajax, google-search-console

in mywebsit, when users click on each subject(url:http://mywebsite/subject/id(1234567)). title and description were showed and content of this subject loaded by ajax.

I add this url (http://mywebsite/subject/id(1234567)) in Fetch as Google (in the google/webmaster) and click on Fetch an Render. Fetch and Render in Googlebot , show ajax content for Rendering tab (the result for "This is how Googlebot saw the page:" show content that was loaded by ajax) but not show in Fetch tab. In Fetch tab exist only source html of my page with out ajax content.

This mean that googlebot crawling will index ajax content of my website?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was no: you have to use ajax crawling scheme as described https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

But yesterday Google changed the rules of the game: 
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Google states "we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers."